# QGIS extract from Vector Tiles

Tags: qgis

QGIS extraction from Vector Tiles?

I am new to QGIS, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I am using vector tiles to load a Basemap of a country, with all streets, buildings, waters,...

I am able to use the "Identify Features" Tool to select a building in the map. In the "Identify Results" pane I am able to select "copy feature" for this building.

After this I can paste the selected building using "Paste Feature As -> Temporary Scratch Layer" into a new layer. But only one building can be copied to the new layer at a time. So to copy ten buildings, I would have to do this ten times.

Is there a way I can extract all buildings in an area to a new Temporary Scratch Area?

Answer (score 0):

I''ve documented the process here with screenshots: https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/Answerquest/diary/402602

Instead of the "Identify Features", use the "Select features by area" button nearby it or a variant of that to select the features you want.
[image]

- You can use Shift / Ctrl to move around the map and add more shapes to the selection.
- Note: stay on a higher/deeper zoom (ie, you should not zoom out too much) so that the shapes aren’t redacted in your view.
- If you zoom out, what vector tile tech does is: it drops some shapes or does simplification / aggregation so that it doesn’t need to load up all the data over the larger area.

Menu > Edit > Copy Features

Menu > Edit > Paste Features As > New Vector Layer

- In the box that opens, select geojson or your preferred format, choose a folder / filename
- Remeber to change the CRS to WGS 84 / EPSG 4326 : That’ll give you lat/lon values. The 3857 one will give huge numbers in your shapefile.

You have now extracted the features you needed to a separate shapefile.

You can now drag-drop your newly created .geojson file onto https://geojson.io or some other shapefile viewer to independently verify that you’ve got the correct data.

It’ll also be carrying any metadata / attributes that the original vector tile layer was having.